# const constructor initialisation failure in Dart

Tags: dart

The following:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Bar {
  final int tender;
  
  const Bar(this.tender);
}

class Foo {
  final int foo;
  final Bar bar;

  const Foo({@required foo})
    : foo = foo,
      bar = const Bar(foo);
}
```

results in the compiler error "Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions" for the attempted initialization `bar = const Bar(foo)`. Why does that line fail, when the preceding line `foo = foo` does not?

**EDIT** Just to further clarify the source of confusion: effectively, it's as if it's ok to const-construct a `Foo` with the argument `foo` (which is unknown at compile-time), but it's not ok to const-construct a `Bar` with the exact same argument. Why?

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823#issuecomment-423900628

Answer (score 3):

The line fails because a `variable` is being passed instead of a `constant/literal` to create the `const` object of `Bar`. The compiler doesn't know what `foo` is going to be at compile time and hence it fails to create a `const Bar(foo)`

Consider this :

```
void main(){
  int someNonConstantValue = 10;
  const Bar(someNonConstantValue);
}
```

Compiler warns here with the same error message

> Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions

This is because `someNonConstantValue` is not a constant.

Now if the code is modified as :

```
void main(){
  const int someConstantValue = 10;
  const Bar(someConstantValue);
}
```

There are no warnings because compiler is now assured that `someConstantValue` is actually constant and wont change anytime (and hence it can compile and optimize the code).

Similarly, In the original example, compiler doesn't give error if changes are made as such to use a `constant literal` for creating `const Bar(`

```
class Bar {
  final int tender;
  const Bar(this.tender);
}

class Foo {
  final int foo;
  final Bar bar;

  const Foo({@required this.foo})
    : bar = const Bar(10);
}
```

**Addition :**
Following the same explanation as above, error is given if `const Foo(` is passed a `variable`

```
void main(){
  int someNonConstantValue = 10;
  const Foo(foo:someNonConstantValue);
}
```

The point you are referring to is the `constructor declaration` inside its own class. It hasn't been invoked with any value yet.

**EDIT:**

[This github issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823) is a discussion on similar lines from early days of Dart.

[This answer](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823#issuecomment-423900628) provides explanation about the same.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense - but my question remains: why, then, does `foo = foo` (in the original example) not fail as well? Effectively, it's as if it's ok to const-construct a `Foo` with the argument `foo` (which, like you say, is unknown at compile-time), but it's not ok to const-construct a `Bar` with the exact same argument.

Comment: You are referring to constructor declaration in its own class. It hasn't been invoked yet.

Comment: Sure. I guess I'm just surprised that, when `const Bar` is invoked from `const Foo`, the compiler doesn't recognise the fact that the only legitimate way to invoke the latter is to pass a const argument to it, which in turn would also be a valid argument to the former. Conversely, if `const Bar` isn't invoked with a compile-time constant, then it can only be because the enveloping `const Foo` hasn't been either.

Comment: To put it another way: the successful invocation of `const Foo` necessitates that `foo` is const, in which case there's no problem invoking `const Bar` with `foo`.

Comment: @jesper [This](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823) is a discussion on similar lines on github from early days of Dart.

Comment: @jesper updated answer with references to discussion, [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/823#issuecomment-423900628) is about the behavior observed

Comment: @ dev-aentgs Thanks for that link, that is super useful. I agree with yjbanov in that thread that it'd be pretty useful to be able to do this kind of initialisation.